# $A^ {1/A} =B^ {1/B} =C^ {1/C} ,A^ {BC} +B^ {AC} +C^ {AB} =729$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $A^
{1/A}
 =B^
{1/B}
 =C^ 
{1/C}
 ,A^
{BC}
 +B^
{AC}
 +C^
{AB}
 =729$
Which of the following equals $A^ 
{1/A}$?

I tried solving it and in the end got $A^{BC}= B^{AC}=C^{BA}= 3^5$ Thus $A^{1/A}=\ ^{ABC}\sqrt {3^5}$

Now I have two doubts. In some of the solutions I have seen, they have concluded that since $A^{BC}= 3^5, A= 3 \ and\ BC = 5$ Thus $ A^{1/A}= 3^{1/3}$. Is this even a correct method? Because using this logic, we can conclude the same that $B^{AC}= 3^5, thus, B= 3 \ and\ AC = 5$ and so does for $C$ making all three $A,B,C= 3 $ which contradicts the rest.

And my second doubt is the answer to my question however is given as $\sqrt2$. How does one get this answer?

Comment: It's almost as if you were supposed to render $A=B=C=2$.  The sum was supposed to be $2×3^4=48$, but someone fat-fingered on the calculator and entered $3×3^4$ getting $729$.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}=K$ (Eq. 1).

Raising each term to the ABC power we get:

$A^{BC}=B^{CA}=C^{AB}=K^{ABC}$,
so the last equation of the question becomes:

$A^{BC}+B^{CA}+C^{AB}=729$ (Eq. 2),

$3*K^{ABC}=729$,

$K^{ABC}=243=3^5$ (Eq. 3).

On the other hand, the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is defined for all x>0, is possitive for all x, and has one maximum at x=e, since, for $y=x^{1/x}$, we have:

$ln(y)=\frac{ln(x)}{x}$,

$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1-ln(x)}{x^2}$ and, since y and $x^2$ are always possitive:
y' is positive for ln(x)<1 (that is, f is an increasing function for x<e) and y' is negative for ln(x)>1 (that is, f is a decreasing function for x>e).

Since the limit of f(x) as x goes to infinity is 1, there are just two values of x with the same f(x) for $1<x<e^{1/e}$ and there is just on value of x with the same f(x) for $0<x\leq 1$ or $x=e^{1/e}$.

Thus there are two possibilities: A=B=C or there are two of them which are identical and the other is different.

1. A=B=C: Then Eq 1 and 3 become:

$3^5=K^{A^3}={A^{1/A}}^{A^3}=A^{\frac{A^3}{A}}=A^{A^{2}}$

and the same relation for B and for C, but I will not write it for simplicity. By taking logarithms in both sides of the equation and operating, we get:

$A^2*ln(A)=5*ln(3)$,

$2A^2*ln(A)=A^2*ln(A^2)=10*ln(3)$.

Introducing the variable $x=ln(A^2)$, the equation becomes:

$x*e^x=10*ln(3)$.

Remembering the Lambert W function defined as: $W(x*e^x)=x$, we get:

$W(10*ln(3))=x=ln(A^2)=2*ln(A)$, so:

$ln(A)=\frac{W(10*ln(3))}{2}$,

$A=B=C=e^{\frac{W(10*ln(3))}{2}}\approx 2.46661$. Then:

$K=(A)^{\frac{1}{A}}\approx 1.44199$.

2. Two of them are equal and the other is different. For example, let us assume that $A=C\neq B$. Then Eq. 2 becomes:

$A^{AB}=3^5=243$, so $AB*ln(A)=5*ln(3)$, $B=\frac{5*ln(3)}{A*ln(A)}$ (Eq. 4),

$B^{A^2}=3^5=243$, so $A^2*ln(B)=5*ln(3)$, $B=e^{\frac{5*ln(3)}{A^2}}=3^{\frac{5}{A^2}}$ (Eq. 5).

When using together Eqs. 4 and 5, three solutions are obtained for A=C, which numerically are approximately:

$A_1=C_1\approx 1.03075$,

$A_2=C_2\approx 1.97791$,

$A_3=C_3\approx 2.46661$.

The last solution is the one we obtained in case 1:

$A_3=B_3=C_3=e^{\frac{W(10*ln(3))}{2}}\approx 2.46661$.

To obtain $B_1$ and $B_2$, first of all we compute $K_1$ and $K_2$ from Eq. 1:

$K_1=(A_1)^{\frac{1}{A_1}}\approx 1.02982$,

$K_2=(A_2)^{\frac{1}{A_2}}\approx 1.41175$.

Then we take into account that A and C are solutions of the following equation:

$x^{1/x}=k$, so we derive a formula for x as a function of k:

$\frac{1}{x}ln(x)=ln(k)$,

$\frac{1}{x}ln(\frac{1}{x})=-\frac{1}{x}ln(x)=-ln(k)$,

$W(-ln(k))=W(\frac{1}{x}ln(\frac{1}{x}))=ln(\frac{1}{x})=-ln(x)=-x*ln(k)$, so finally:

$x=\frac{-W(-ln(k))}{ln(k)}$.

Using this formula, we obtain:

$B_1=\frac{-W(-ln(K_1))}{ln(K_1)}\approx 175.953$,

$B_2=\frac{-W(-ln(K_2))}{ln(K_2)}\approx 4.07186$.

All the other possible solutions can be obtained by permutations of A, B and C. Since there is a solution with A=B=C and two solutions for each variable being different than the other two ones, there is a total of 7 solutions.

Note: I have edited the answer to include the first possible value of $A^{1/A}$.

Comment: Its not $A^{BC}+B^{AC}+C^{AB}$. It is $A^{BC} \times B^{AC} \times C^{AB}$

Comment: In the original question I see plus signs in the second equation. Anyway, I have written another answer considering multiplication signs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A^{1/A} = B^{1/B} = C^{1/C} = k$. Now, raise each term to the $ABC$ power and you get:
$A^{BC} = B^{AC} = C{AB} = k^{ABC}$ We know that $A^{BC} + B^{AC} + C^{AB} = 729$.

So
it becomes,

$k^{ABC}\times k^{ABC}\times k^{ABC}=729$

$(k^{ABC})^3 = 729$

$k^{ABC} = 9$

$k = 9^{\frac{1}{ABC}}$

So, $A^{1/A} = 9^{1/ABC}$

Hope it helps

Comment: Why do you write $k^{ABC}\times k^{ABC}\times k^{ABC}=729$? It looks wrong.

Comment: @311411, There's a typo in the question. Its not **+**. It is $\times$

Answer (score 0):

Although in the original question I see plus signs in the second equation, I am solving again the question, this time as if there were multiplication signs, as I have been suggested. The difference in the way of solving it is small anyway.

Let $A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}=K$ (Eq. 1).

Raising each term to the ABC power we get:

$A^{BC}=B^{CA}=C^{AB}=K^{ABC}$,
so the last equation of the question becomes:

$A^{BC}\times B^{CA}\times C^{AB}=729$ (Eq. 2),

$({K^{ABC}})^3=729=3^6$,

$K^{ABC}=3^2=9$ (Eq. 3).

On the other hand, the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is defined for all x>0, is possitive for all x, and has one maximum at x=e, since, for $y=x^{1/x}$, we have:

$ln(y)=\frac{ln(x)}{x}$,

$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1-ln(x)}{x^2}$ and, since y and $x^2$ are always possitive:
y' is positive for ln(x)<1 (that is, f is an increasing function for x<e) and y' is negative for ln(x)>1 (that is, f is a decreasing function for x>e).

Since the limit of f(x) as x goes to infinity is 1, there are just two values of x with the same f(x) for $1<x<e^{1/e}$ and there is just on value of x with the same f(x) for $0<x\leq 1$ or $x=e^{1/e}$.

Thus there are two possibilities: A=B=C or there are two of them which are identical and the other is different.

1. A=B=C: Then Eq 1 and 3 become:

$3^2=K^{A^3}=({A^{1/A}})^{A^3}=A^{\frac{A^3}{A}}=A^{A^{2}}$

and the same relation for B and for C, but I will not write it for simplicity. By taking logarithms in both sides of the equation and operating, we get:

$A^2*ln(A)=2*ln(3)$,

$2A^2*ln(A)=A^2*ln(A^2)=4*ln(3)$.

Introducing the variable $x=ln(A^2)$, the equation becomes:

$x*e^x=4*ln(3)$.

Remembering the Lambert W function defined as: $W(x*e^x)=x$, we get:

$W(4*ln(3))=x=ln(A^2)=2*ln(A)$, so:

$ln(A)=\frac{W(4*ln(3))}{2}$,

$A=B=C=e^{\frac{W(4*ln(3))}{2}}\approx 2.46661$. Then:

$K=(A)^{\frac{1}{A}}\approx 1.44199$.

2. Two of them are equal and the other is different. For example, let us assume that $A=C\neq B$. Then Eq. 2 becomes:

$A^{AB}=3^2=9$, so $AB*ln(A)=2*ln(3)$, $B=\frac{2*ln(3)}{A*ln(A)}$ (Eq. 4),

$B^{A^2}=3^2=9$, so $A^2*ln(B)=2*ln(3)$, $B=e^{\frac{2*ln(3)}{A^2}}=3^{\frac{2}{A^2}}$ (Eq. 5).

When using together Eqs. 4 and 5, just one solution is obtained for A=C, being this solution the same as that found in case 1, so this case does not add any further solution, being the solution to this question unique.

Comment: Why to solve a problem here, that was not asked by the OP (original poster = Ruchi)???

Comment: The title has plus signs in the second equation, but the abstract is computed as if they were multiplication signs and some people say there is a mistake, so I prefer to solve also the possibility of a second equation with multiplication signs.